# How do I set ng-bootstrap modal component content members?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

This is the open method from the sample in the documentation, using a component as content:

```
open() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
}
```

What I would like to do is to use the component in a similar fashion below and able to set the name.

```
open(content) {
  this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
    this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
  }, (reason) => {
    this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
  });
}
```

How can I do that?

I am relatively new to both Typescript and Angular 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a really newbie question.

The solution is

```
open() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  modalRef.result.then((result) => {
    this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
  }, (reason) => {
    this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
  });
}
```

Comment: Was looking exactly for that. It looks a bit uncommon that you have to open() first and then set properties... I think they better have create() and open() separately.